# How to show a published property in a class diagram

Tags: delphi, uml

At the moment I am busy creating UML diagrams for my application and I ran into this question. I know in a class diagram a class member (field, attribute, operation etc..) can only have the following visibility options:

- Private
- Public
- Package
- Protected

The question that I have is regarding class members in Delphi that are `published`; how do you show this in your Class Diagram?

`Published` members have the same visibility as `Public` members, but they have RTTI available, so there is a slight difference between the two... So in my opinion it is not completely correct to just put them in as `public` members, anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Annotate it like this: `<<published>>`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's a good idea, I also use this when I want to show that a class member should be implemented as `property`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this cannot be done by UML. The published keyword is (as far as I currently know of) Delphi only, whereas UML is a standard to use with all languages.

So what I would do, is to create a custom flag when designing the UML classes. These would show that you actually mean published instead of public. However, the visibility is the same, so is it actually necessary for you?

On the other hand, the differences are not that significant, the visibility is the same and you are right about the fact that published properties have RunTime Type Information available.

Comment: necessary is not what I would like to call it, for design it is not a big difference whether you use `public` or `published`.

But if you go the 'golden way' you would like to have a design that 100% matches your code, and you do not want to have a developer implementing it in another way as you've intended it in your design.